# How do you modify this struct in Golang to accept two different results?

Tags: json, go, struct, dynamic

For the following JSON response `{"table_contents":[{"id":100,"description":"text100"},{"id":101,"description":"text101"},{"id":1,"description":"text1"}]}`

All you have to do is to produce the following code to execute it properly and be able to reads fields from the struct, such as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyStruct1 struct {
    TableContents []struct {
        ID          int
        Description string
    } `json:"table_contents"`
}

func main() {
    result:= []byte(`{"table_contents":[{"id":100,"description":"text100"},{"id":101,"description":"text101"},{"id":1,"description":"text1"}]}`)
    var container MyStruct1
    err := json.Unmarshal(result, &container)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(" [0] Error message: " + err.Error())
        return
    }
    
    for i := range container.TableContents {
        fmt.Println(container.TableContents[i].Description)
    }
    
}
```

But how do you deal with the following JSON response? `{"table_contents":[[{"id":100,"description":"text100"},{"id":101,"description":"text101"}],{"id":1,"description":"text1"}]}` You can either get this response or the one above, it is important to modify the struct to accept both.

I did something like this, with the help of internet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyStruct1 struct {
    TableContents []TableContentUnion `json:"table_contents"`
}

type TableContentClass struct {
    ID          int        
    Description string
}

type TableContentUnion struct {
    TableContentClass      *TableContentClass
    TableContentClassArray []TableContentClass
}

func main() {
    result:= []byte(`{"table_contents":[[{"id":100,"description":"text100"},{"id":101,"description":"text101"}],{"id":1,"description":"text1"}]}`)
    var container MyStruct1
    err := json.Unmarshal(result, &container)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(" [0] Error message: " + err.Error())
        return
    }
    
    for i := range container.TableContents {
        fmt.Println(container.TableContents[i])
    }
    
}
```

but it does not go past the error message :(

- [0] Error message: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field MyStruct1.table_contents of type main.TableContentUnion*

Been struggling to come up with a solution for hours. If someone could help I would be happy. Thank you for reading. Let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `table_contents` you have two type options (json object or list of json objects). What you can do is to unmarshall into an interface and then run type-check on it when using it:

```golang
type MyStruct1 struct {
    TableContents []interface{} `json:"table_contents"`
}

...

for i := range container.TableContents {
    switch container.TableContents[i].(type){
    case map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Println("json object")
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println("list")
    }
}
```

From there you can use some library (e.g. https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) to map unmarshalled struct to your `TableContentClass` type. See PoC playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/NhVUhQayeL_C

Comment: Thank you, the go playground code seems to be what I was looking for!

Comment: This is actually not a very good idea as the json unmarshalling dictates the structure of your types. Unless this is only a temporary type which is then written to the real structure. The proper solution is a custom UnmarshalJSON function as described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Custom `UnmarshalJSON` function

You can also create a custom UnmarshalJSON function on the object that has the 2 possibilities. In you case that would be `TableContentUnion`.

In the custom unmarshaller you can then decide how to unmarshal the content.

```golang
func (s *TableContentUnion) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // Note that we get `b` as bytes, so we can also manually check to see
    // if it is an array (starts with `[`) or an object (starts with `{`)
    var jsonObj interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &jsonObj); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch jsonObj.(type) {
    case map[string]interface{}:
        // Note: instead of using json.Unmarshal again, we could also cast the interface
        // and build the values as in the example above
        var tableContentClass TableContentClass
        if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &tableContentClass); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        s.TableContentClass = &tableContentClass
    case []interface{}:
        // Note: instead of using json.Unmarshal again, we could also cast the interface
        // and build the values as in the example above
        if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &s.TableContentClassArray); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    default:
        return errors.New("TableContentUnion.UnmarshalJSON: unknown content type")
    }
    return nil
}
```

The rest then works like in your test code that was failing before. Here the working [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SyDwO6u8B_J)

## Unmarshal to `map` and manually build struct

You can always unmarshal a json (with an object at the root) into a `map[string]interface{}`. Then you can iterate things and further unmarshal them after checking what type they are.

Working example:

```golang
func main() {
    result := []byte(`{"table_contents":[[{"id":100,"description":"text100"},{"id":101,"description":"text101"}],{"id":1,"description":"text1"}]}`)

    var jsonMap map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(result, &jsonMap)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(" [0] Error message: " + err.Error())
        return
    }

    cts, ok := jsonMap["table_contents"].([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        // Note: nil or missing 'table_contents" will also lead to this path.
        fmt.Println("table_contents is not a slice")
        return
    }
    var unions []TableContentUnion
    for _, content := range cts {
        var union TableContentUnion
        if contents, ok := content.([]interface{}); ok {
            for _, content := range contents {
                contCls := parseContentClass(content)
                if contCls == nil {
                    continue
                }
                union.TableContentClassArray = append(union.TableContentClassArray, *contCls)
            }
        } else {
            contCls := parseContentClass(content)
            union.TableContentClass = contCls
        }
        unions = append(unions, union)
    }

    container := MyStruct1{
        TableContents: unions,
    }
    for i := range container.TableContents {
        fmt.Println(container.TableContents[i])
    }
}

func parseContentClass(value interface{}) *TableContentClass {
    m, ok := value.(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    return &TableContentClass{
        ID:          int(m["id"].(float64)),
        Description: m["description"].(string),
    }
}
```

This is most useful if the json has too many variations. For cases like this it might also make sense sometimes to switch to a json package that works differently like https://github.com/tidwall/gjson which gets values based on their path.

Answer (score 0):

Use [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) to capture the varying parts of the JSON document. Unmarshal each raw message as appropriate.

```
func (ms *MyStruct1) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {

    // Declare new type with same base type as MyStruct1.
    // This breaks recursion in call to json.Unmarshal below.
    type x MyStruct1

    v := struct {
        *x

        // Override TableContents field with raw message.
        TableContents []json.RawMessage `json:"table_contents"`
    }{
        // Unmarshal all but TableContents directly to the
        // receiver.
        x: (*x)(ms),
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    // Unmarahal raw elements as appropriate.

    for _, tcData := range v.TableContents {
        if bytes.HasPrefix(tcData, []byte{'{'}) {
            var v TableContentClass
            if err := json.Unmarshal(tcData, &v); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            ms.TableContents = append(ms.TableContents, v)
        } else {
            var v []TableContentClass
            if err := json.Unmarshal(tcData, &v); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            ms.TableContents = append(ms.TableContents, v)

        }
    }
    return nil

}
```

Use it like this:

```
var container MyStruct1
err := json.Unmarshal(result, &container)
if err != nil {
    // handle error 
}
```

[Run it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-JrTbCEPn6o).

This approach does not add any outside dependencies.  The function code does not need to modified when fields are added or removed from `MyStruct1` or `TableContentClass`.